# Can I use dictionaries to keep track of objects in Python?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, object

Does it make sense to use dictionaries to store groups of class objects? My program would have several hundred subClassA objects, and about 10 subClassB objects each. I'm not very experienced with OOP so if there is a better way please let me know.

```
class root:
#List of key:object pairs for subclassA objects
sublassA = {}

    class subclassA:
        #List of key:object pairs for subclassB objects
        subclassB = {}

        class subclassB:
```

Comment: There is no reason a class can't use a dictionary to keep track of subclass instances. But your approach to subclassing is wrong. Don't nest the class declarations. Instead define all 3 classes at the same level as `root` and indicate the subclassing using `class subclassA (root):` and `class subclassB(subclassA):`. Though it looks to me that you don't need subclasses at all. If `subclassA` is something *contained* in `root`, then `root` is simply a container and not a superclass.

Comment: Thank you for the nesting correction. Also, subclassA would have its own methods and properties, as would subclassB, so I think I still want to use subclasses to define them? Just to clarify, my data is: root = Stock Market, subclassA = A stock, subclassB = Period, where "Period" contains the actual time vs. price data for the stock.

Comment: @peepsed This statement isn't clear. If each class has its *own* methods and properties, then there is no need to subclass anything, even if you are nesting one class within another, for example. But if each class *inherits* or uses common methods or properties defined in a base class, then definitely subclassing could be a good idea in that case.